# MongoDB Aggregate query to find missing attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a huge collection of objects in MongoDB which looks something like below.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61dde"
    },
    "employee": "Joe",
    "dateTime": "2022-06-24T01:31:23.41Z",
    "fileContents": {
        "inventory": [
        {
                "attribute": "A",
                "attributeInventory": [
                    {
                        "atrributeCompId": "v1",
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeCompId": "v2",
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
                "attribute": "B",
                "attributeInventory": [
                    {
                        "atrributeCompId": "b1",
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
                "attribute": "C",
                "attributeInventory": [
                    {
                        "atrributeCompId": "C1",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the collection, for every employee these attributes are mandatory and each attribute has its own set of componentIds (atrributeCompId). The issue is that for Attribute "A" only the componentId can be more than 1, i.e, v1 and v2 and they both are mandatory. But there are lots of objects where either one is missing. Mostly the missing one is v1.

Now, I am trying to list down all the employees where v1 is missing, but not able to list them correctly.

Here is my query for reference :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$fileContents.inventory"},
    {"$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
                 {"$match": 
                    {"$and" : [
                          {"attribute" : "A"},
               {"attributeInventory.attrbuteCompId" : "v1"}
            ]
            }
         },
            null
           ]
         },
         null
         ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          "documents": {
          "$push": {
              "employee": "$employee"
              }
          }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
         "_id": false
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: `inventory` is an array. What about when there are more elements than just one? Does every element shall have `{ atrributeCompId: "v1" }` or just one?

Comment: inventory is an array and there will always be more than 1 element in an array. However, attribute : A is mandatory for every employee and will always be present in every object. That's why I was first trying to match the data of attribute : A as I only want to check the missing {atrributeCompId : "v1"} for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not fully clear to me, a starting point could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         v1: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$fileContents.inventory",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.attribute", "A"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         v1: {
            $map: {
               input: "$v1",
               in: { $in: ["v1", "$$this.attributeInventory.atrributeCompId"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { v1: { $allElementsTrue: "$v1" } } },
   { $match: { v1: false } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NnMpvb-dvQ)

Comment: I have updated the question now. Hope it makes more sense

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Any other thoughts as how this can be accomplished ? I am trying to get the list of all such employees who are missing attributeCompId "V1" for attribute "A". But not able to get that correctly